# Laravel, Simple and Correct way for relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to list related categories of related brand with this logic.

**Products Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('{Brand}/{Category}/{Product}', 'ProductsController@show');
Route::get('{Brand}/{Category}', 'ProductsController@index');
```

1st route, for example; Samsung/phones should list all of Samsung's phones with following code part. Is there another way to make these codes simple? And this query returns null. I checked that query is getting correct columns but returns null.

```
use App\Product;
use App\Brand;
use App\Category;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {   
        $category = $request->Category;
        $cat_id = Category::select('id')
                    ->where('slug',$category)
                    ->get();

        $brand = $request->Brand;
        $br_id = Brand::select('id')
                ->where('slug', $brand)
                ->get();

        $products = Product::select('id','name','slug')
                ->where('category_id', $cat_id)
                ->where('brand_id', $br_id)
                ->get();

        return view('products.index', compact('products'));
    }
}
```

**Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model
    {
        public function brands()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand');
        }

        public function categories()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
        }
    }
```

**Category.php**

```
class Category extends Model
{

    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Brand');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Comment: May be your index function route is wrong because you have to pass parameters in your route when parameters not pass in your `index()`

Comment: @SaurabhDhariwal but the url won't be as i want. I just want to go on with this clean url. Also, index function parameters are getting from url one by one; like `$request->Brand` and `$request->Category`

Comment: You pass parameters as id for both (i.e brand, category)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all read the docs about laravel relationships: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

The reason your current code is not working is because in your route you ask for parameters:

```
Route::get('{Brand}/{Category}', 'ProductsController@index');
```

But in your index() method on your ProductsController you have not included these parameters.

```
 public function index(Request $request, Brand $brand, Category $category)
```

The second problem in your code is that you are not using your relationships at all. Your current controller just makes a new eloquent query.

Example of getting all the products for the given category using the method you have defined on your Category Model:

```
public function index(Request $request, Brand $brand, Category $category)
{   

    $products = $category->products;

    return view('products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Example of extending this with the given brand:

```
public function index(Request $request, Brand $brand, Category $category)
{   

    $products = $category->products()->where('brand_id', $brand->id)->get();

    return view('products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

**UPDATE**

As noted in the comments, the URL parameters are slugs and not ids, so auto route-model-binding will not work. An updated solution with slugs:

```
public function index(Request $request, $brand, $category)
{
    $categoryModel = Category::where('slug', $category)->firstOrFail();
    $brandModel = Brand::where('slug', $brand)->firstOrFail();   

    $products = $categoryModel->products()->where('brand_id', $brandModel->id)->get();

    return view('products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Further improving your code would be to add a scope or helper method so you can do something like `Brand::FindBySlug($slug);`

Comment: I think this will work but im working with slugs, how should i do that ? First of all, i'll get the brand slug and category slug requested and then find related products.

Comment: Using the defined relationships will only work with primary keys, if no primary keys are overwritten in the relationship methods it we auto-add them like this: category_id / brand_id. The above code will have to be changed to a where statement based on the 'slug' or create a dedicated local scope to do that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using get method at last that will give you array not only one value. Could you please try with below code. This might help

```
use App\Product;
use App\Brand;
use App\Category;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    $category = $request->Category;
    $cat_id = Category::where('slug',$category)->value('id);

    $brand = $request->Brand;
    $br_id = Brand::where('slug', $brand)->value('id);

    $products = Product::select('id','name','slug')
            ->where('category_id', $cat_id)
            ->where('brand_id', $br_id)
            ->get();

    return view('products.index', compact('products'));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function index($brand, $category,Request $request)
    {   

        $products = Product::select('id','name','slug')
                ->where('category_id', $category)
                ->where('brand_id', $brand)
                ->get();

        return view('products.index', compact('products'));
    }
```